# Why my element disappears immediately after appending it?

Tags: javascript, forms, events

i'm trying to do a simple todo app exercise, i don't know why but my list item gets appended but disappeares right away. Any suggestion?

```
    /* jshint esversion: 6 */

    window.onload = function () {
        var taskList = document.querySelector('#taskList');
        var form = document.querySelector('form');
        let count = 1;
        form.addEventListener("submit", function(){
            var task = document.querySelector('input').value;
            let li = document.createElement('li');
            li.append(count + '  ' + task);
            taskList.append(li);
        });

    };
```

Comment: My guess based on this info is that you don't `preventDefault` on submit and element doesn't disappear, page just reloads.

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

form.submit submits the form data to the url listed in `action`. Given the issue you are reporting, my suspicion is that your action is the same page. So on reload, the LI that you dynamically added is no longer there because of page reload. Make sense?

```
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(){
        var task = document.querySelector('input').value;
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.append(count + '  ' + task);
        taskList.append(li);
    });
```

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks

Comment: Although your explanation is correct, I don't get why you just copy and pasted the code - without showing how to stop the form submitting